# Clustering algorithms puts data points that are visually far apart in same cluster

Tags: mixed-model, clustering, k-means

I am trying to cluster a very large set of data points, of roughly `(20000, 100)` shape. I could not run density based DBSCAN or SpectralClustering due to the enormous amount of memory required. However when I do K-Means (with appropriate K selected with the 'elbow' method) or GMM, I see that points that are visually far apart and should not be labeled in a single cluster are grouped together.

My guess is such clusterings are not good for sparse data. Any suggestion would be great.

I'm attaching the clustered scatter plot (`X`, `Y` are normalized to fit in `[0, 1]`) to show what I am saying. I varied the `random_sate`, `n_init` but results are similar.

[image: K means]

GMM

[image: GMM]

Edit:

Regarding `X` and `Y`, these are coordinates in 2 D plane. urrently I have about 20000 `X` values, and 100 `Y` values. How I represented the data in coordinate form is by taking all possible pairs out of these.

So in this representation it is 2 dimensional, not high dimensional. But number of coordinate is large.

Comment: What is X and Y in the plot?

Comment: *"the clustered scatter plot"* how did you create this plot out of 100 columns?

Comment: How did you or the algorithm decide on the number of clusters?

Comment: For K-means by the popular elbow method. For GMM it is trial and error. I could not use density based approaches that takes epsilon distance as parameter. Those doesn't converge in reasonable time.

Answer (score 3):

High-dimensional data are unfortunately inherently hard to deal with - for clustering as well as for other use cases. That low-dimensional projections or MDS show large gaps between point in the same cluster does not tell you much.

See [Hayes (2011)](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/an-adventure-in-the-nth-dimension) or [Bouveyon et al. (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2007.02.009). You may also want to take a look at [previous threads tagged both "clustering" and "high-dimensional".](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering+high-dimensional)

Comment: Thanks but I do not thing it is high dimensional in this representation. I edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: Yes, *this representation* is low dimensional. But you have 100 dimensions that you cluster over, and that is where the problems come from. Or not? What else precisely do you mean by "100 `Y` values"?

Comment: The 20000*100 `(X, Y)` pairs can be considered as location coordinates on ground.

Comment: say for k-means I did
`coords = numpy.vstack([X, Y[) # a (2000000,2) array`
`Kmeans(coord, other params)`